# Sum values with same name

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets with a long list of names and amounts. Many of the names are duplicates. For example:

```
John  | 10
Bill  | 2
Susan | 3
Frank | 4
Sally | 10
John  | 2
Susan | 2
John  | 3
```

Is there any automated way to combine all of the values so I get a list without any duplicate names and a single sum of all of each person's entry?

For example:

```
John  | 15
Bill  | 2
Susan | 5
Sally | 10
```

Answer (score 66):

Assuming names are in A1:A8, amounts in B1:B8, first we need unique name list in D1:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A8)
```

Then use conditional sum in E1:

```
=SUMIF(A$1:A$8,D1,B$1:B$8)
```

Please note `$` prefix before cell number. This will keep the same ranges when we copy cell contents down (select cells E1:E8 and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

Comment: Great! Just want to add that in some locales you need to replace comma with semi colon, i.e. =SUMIF(A$1:A$8;D1;B$1:B$8).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted. How do you sort it in descending order by the amount? In this example, John would come first, then Sally, Susan and finally Bill.

Comment: SImple :) =SORT(A2:B92;FALSE)

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 34):

If you use the [Query Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) then you don't have to worry about the list growing and not having copied the sum formula down far enough.

If names are in A:A and amounts are in B:B, then in D1 enter:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select A, sum(B) group by A")
```

There is a much more thorough answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36111), with screenshots even.

Comment: What if you had a header row? Would you have to know specific start and end row indices then? Aha, looks like I can specify the # of header rows...https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

Comment: This is the cleanest method, I think.

Note that if you don't want to query the entire spreadsheet (for example, if you have unrelated data below), you can specify a range like A2:B28)

Also, I like to use the CONCATENATE function to combine multiple columns from my spreadsheets into one row for grouping - like Lastname, Firstname.

Answer (score 10):

I will give a shot at this as well: I prefer to use the filter function. Using column selection, allows for the table to automatically grow when adding "new" data:

```
FILTER(B:B;A:A=D2)
```

If you're having a header, you can change it accordingly:

```
FILTER($B$2:B;$A$2:A=D2)
```

Making the subseqent summation is easy:

```
SUM(FILTER($B$2:B;$A$2:A=D2))
```

See example: [File I prepared with example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDdQTzlKVXhodlFOdThLbXc0c2FhVGc)

Comment: How do I make this formula auto expand to the bottom of the sheet?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Pivot Table Report ...](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1258755&answer=1272898&rd=1) under the `Data` Menu.

You will need to make sure that the first row has field names.

Comment: This is actually easier than the formula answers.

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer. Forget formulas for such a grouping task.

Answer (score 1):

Use following formula!

Header: `=UNIQUE(A:A)`

Value: `=SUMIF(A:A,UNIQUE(A:A),B:B)`