# How to group data in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have the following table in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
Name | Value
A    | 10
B    | 100
A    | 20
B    | 200
C    | 1000
```

How can I create another table based on a query:

```
select name, sum(value), count(value) from table group by name
```

so it looks like this:

```
Name | SUM   | COUNT
A    | 30    | 2
B    | 300   | 2
C    | 1000  | 1
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

By using the `QUERY` function you can achieve your goal.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:B6;"select A, sum(B), count(B) group by A")
```

### Screenshot

[image: example formula output]

Using other functions, makes it achievable as well.

add this formula in A2:

```
=UNIQUE(Data!A2:A)
```

add the following formulas in B2 and C2 and copy down to B4 and C4 respectively

```
=SUM(FILTER(Data!$B$2:B;Data!$A$2:A=A2))
=COUNTA(FILTER(Data!$B$2:B;Data!$A$2:A=A2))
```

### Example

I've made an example file for you: **[QUERY vs. FUNCTIONS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KdQaTO6hNG0NeJnpgm1EJBn9saThoCwzZa54IM06Kk/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#overview

Comment: Google sheets [docs on query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Answer (score 57):

You can use [Pivot Tables](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/05/pivot-tables-in-google-spreadsheets.html) to group data in Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 11):

Why not using [Pivot Table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)?
It will give you more options and controls than writing a custom formula.
Controls live Add Columns, Rows, Values, Filters

[image]

Comment: Nice answer with image, but why not edit the previous answer and just add the image?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not happy to click through to a blog to get my answer so this is my preferred answer.