# Grouping data as percentage or count based on responses and age groups

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I've data collected from google forms, with answers from the questions placed in those forms.

The data looks as follows the first column has a variety of answers from 
`20-25, 26-30, 31-35` and so on (which are the age groups). The second column has the answers `yes` or `no`

```
| your age | answer |
---------------------
| 25-30    |  yes   |
---------------------
| 25-30    |  no    |
---------------------
| 41-45    |  yes   |
---------------------
| 25-30    |  yes   |
```

The result I want to achieve is this

```
| grouped age | answered yes | answered no |
---------------------------------------------
| 25-30       |  20          |  30         |
---------------------------------------------
| 31-35       |  10          |  15         |
```

So the first column has the available age group answers, and the second and third one the count for each group based on the answer from the second column.

I've tried to do this according to this method [How to group data in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/how-to-group-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet?newreg=edfaf05bd95d4b028f003ff0447f6a6e)
but with no luck

The reason for this it to make a chart based on the age groups and their preferences.

Answer (score 1):

1. Besides of `group by` use `pivot`.

   ```
   =query(A:C,"select A COUNT(C) group by A pivot B")
   ```

   Note: query can't use an aggregation function an grouping/pivoting on the same column, so you should add an auxiliary column C having 1 for each row.
2. To set a custom column header use `label`

For details see [Query Language Reference (Version 0.7)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: Hmm, I get the same results but only in a different structure right now I'm trying =QUERY(odp!C2:H231;"select count(H) pivot C ") but it yields the same results as =QUERY(odp!C2:H231;"select (C), count(H) group by C") just horizontally

Comment: Sorry instead of "instead" I should say besides. If you need further help add teh formulas that you tried to the question and a sample spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link.

Comment: @adam I edited my answer.

Comment: I'll try this. In the meantime i made a well not so elegant solution by using where since the are only two options in the second table (yes, or no) but i cannot get the second label to say 'yes' =QUERY(odp!C2:H231;"select (C), count(H) where H contains 'yes' group by C label C 'Age'")

Comment: OK got it i know not the best solution since i had to change the query manually to get the results but maybe it will help someone =QUERY(odp!C2:H231;"select (C), count(H) where H contains 'yes' group by C label C 'Age', count(H) 'yes' ")

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17iVFWaXNlZYJU_U3gmVvQJrL304PXC5Od7oaZrPYnUM/edit?usp=sharing the link to the spreadsheet

Comment: `query can't use an aggregation function an grouping/pivoting on the same column,`. Actually, It can.`Select(A),count(A)` will work with grouping A and/or pivoting.