# Google SpreadSheets query: how to join "grouped by" cells in a list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Suppose I have this table:

```
| Name   | Amount | Category |
| name_1 | 10     | A        |
| name_2 | 2      | B        |
| name_3 | 3      | B        |
| name_4 | 6      | C        |
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/how-to-group-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet), I know how to write a query that groups the rows by category, and gives me sum of `Amount` by category, like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:C5,"select C, sum(B) group by C order by sum(B)")
```

[image]

My question is: how do I add a third row to my query, such that it lists the `Name` of every row in that group (possibly, but not necessarily, comma-separated)?

In other words, I'd like the result to look like this:

```
|   | sum | items          |
| B | 5   | name_2, name_3 |
| C | 6   | name_1         |
| A | 10  | name_4         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()`. Put this formula in cell `C11`:

`=iferror( textjoin( ", ", true, filter(A$2:A$5, C$2:C$5 = A11) ) )`

...and copy the formula cell down.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it seems the filter didn't find any matches. I've created a public scratch pad here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JunonZKbqIGn2e9Pwcii_Qewv4E4wWEYyLvNY3jrQXs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Right, you need replace the reference to column B with a reference to column C. Edited the answer. See your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thank you :D