# Check for criterion in multiple non-adjacent columns, display results from 1 column to the right

Tags: google-sheets

Previously posted but closed as duplicate with link to the question below

Original question: [Sum values to the right of criteria in multicolumn range](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154963/sum-values-to-the-right-of-criteria-in-multicolumn-range)
Proposed answer/duplicate: [Sum values with same name](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25798/sum-values-with-same-name)

Original question
I apologize in advance because I don't even know how to describe this best.

But, I have 3 3-column ranges in which the left columns are IDs, the middle columns are names, and the right column is quantity I'd like to sum up.

There is some overlap between ID's in left columns.

I created a column of sorted unique ID's but could not come up with formulas to populate the names and then sum the values.

Ideally, the formula would also work with "arrayformula" as the columns may get very lengthy.

Here's an example spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z6qx4JGl-RGm3GExhEcxoTby7DTRSaRfLo-3VGwucvk/edit?usp=sharing

THANK YOU all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query()` like this:

```
=query( 
  { G1:I; J2:L; N2:P }, 
  "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) 
   where Col1 is not null 
   group by Col1, Col2", 
  1 
)
```

This is an array formula that creates the whole result table in one go. Place the formula in row 1 of a free column with another free column to the right.

Comment: Hi there, thank you.  That's missing the name column.  I updated my spreadsheet with an example

Comment: Edited the formula per your new requirements.

Comment: I appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification to @doubleunary's formula above, accounting for your comment to him:

```
=QUERY( 
  { G1:I; J2:L; N2:P }, 
  "Select Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3) 
   WHERE Col1 Is Not Null 
   GROUP BY Col1, Col2 LABEL SUM(Col3) 'TOTAL QTY'", 
  1 
)
```

Make sure that you have three open columns and that you place the above formula in the top cell of the leftmost of those three columns.

If this works as expected, please credit doubleunary with "Best Answer."

Comment: thank you so much for the extra help and handing the prize to doublenary.

Comment: Glad it all worked out.